# What is wrong with this Javascript script?

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

I'm writing a simple timer this way:

```
   function timer(init){
     console.log(init);
     setTimeout(function(init){
       timer(init+1);
     },1000);
   }

   timer(1);
```

It's a recursive function (Note: I am aware it is an infinite loop, just not important now). However as simple as it seems, it fails as the output of each interval is **NaN**, and not an increased number as expected.
The function is so simple that I cannot figure out what the issue is. What am I missing?

Comment: `function(init){...}` makes `init` to be `undefined`. `setTimeout` does not pass an argument to the callback. Remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are overriding the value of `init` by passing an argument to `setTimeout`'s callback function.

```
function timer(init) {
  console.log(init);
  setTimeout(function() {
    timer(init+1);
  },1000);
}

timer(1);
```

This way the `init` value is the one you passed into the `timer` call.

Answer (score 1):

The function body you're passing in to setTimeout is a callback function, no arguments are passed to it (because setTimeout doesn't pass any).

```js
function timer(init) {
  console.log(init);
  setTimeout(function() {
    timer(init + 1);
  }, 1000);
}

timer(1);
```

---

The simplest way to do it would be something like this:

```js
var t = 0;

function timer() {
  console.log(++t);
  setTimeout(timer, 1000);
}

timer();
```

Comment: You might want to add at least *some* explanation.

Comment: I not quite see the purpose of the second example. No one would write code like that (I hope).

Comment: Sorry, @FelixKling, was writing it, then decided the show the way with passing the argument. No purpose at all, just showing where the argument should go.

Comment: Okay, I've decided to replace it with a version that uses an external variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed an anonymous function as a parameter instead of a string, the latter method shouldn't even work per the ECMAScript specification but browsers are just lenient.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    timer(init+1);
}, 1000)
```

Comment: The OP already seems to do that... not sure I see your point? Also the function doesn't have to be anonymous. Fun fact: `setTimeout` is not even part of ECMAScript, it's part of the HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#timers